# Can I use Ruby with Shoes for GUI for a multiple choice test app?

Tags: ruby, database, shoes

I'm trying to make a simple multiple choice question app. Is this possible on ruby?
I've tried using shoes but I don't know how to create multiple classes and a GUI that uses them.
I'm also trying to connect all of this to a database.
I'm having trouble in understanding how to connect all of this together.

Comment: Are you having trouble figuring out how to use Shoes, or on how to make a gui for an app?

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how to use different gems together.
I worked a bit on it and I've the interface and the classes going but i need to connect to a mysql database and whenever i try to install the mysql gem i get a could not find a valid gem error

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments the main problem seems to be with using the mysql gem part.

Gem usage depends on the version of shoes you are using. For `green_shoes` you should be good with the standard gems, but it is unmaintained. Shoes 3.1 has problems with gems that have C extensions (such as mysql). Shoes 3.2 should work. With Shoes4 you can't install the normal Ruby gems with C extensions as it uses JRuby and C extension support in JRuby is disabled. You have to use different gems to connect to the database, functionality is the same. A starting point might be [activerecord-jdbc](https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter).